# How do I reset the git master branch to the upstream branch in a forked repository?

Tags: git

I've completely messed up the master branch of my forked git repo.

I want to completely reset the master branch that was pushed to my fork with the contents of the upstream master repo.  I have no interest in retaining any master branch changes or history.

The simplest approach would have been to delete my forked repo and refork from the upstream project.  However, I have work in other pushed branches that I don't want to lose.

Thus how to I reset my pushed master branch with the upstream master?

---

```
git clone https://myrepo.git
cd myrepo
git remote add upstream https://upstream.git
git fetch upstream
```

Where do I go from here to reset my local and remote master branches with the upstream master?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You can reset your local master branch to the upstream version and push it to your origin repository.

Assuming that "upstream" is the original repository and "origin" is your fork:

```
# ensures current branch is master
git checkout master

# pulls all new commits made to upstream/master
git pull upstream master

# this will delete all your local changes to master
git reset --hard upstream/master

# take care, this will delete all your changes on your forked master
git push origin master --force
```

(You can define the original repo as "upstream" with `git remote add upstream /url/to/original/repo`.)

Comment: It should probably be `git reset --hard upstream/master` to reset the working directory, too. But your answer is correct nevertheless.

Comment: Not using "--hard" also works while keeping local changes. I would do the hard reset in a sperated step to possibly inspect the diff.

Comment: Need to call `git fetch upstream` first

Comment: As @HenryE notes, failing to fetch upstream changes first with `git fetch upstream` typically yields the following non-human-readable error: `"fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."`

Comment: Just be careful that the forced push automatically closes all open pull-requests you made for the upstream. I wasn't aware of this, which was a bit of a surprise.

Comment: This solution does not work. The command `git pull upstream master` created a lot of conflicts.

Comment: The original solution was edited to "pull". Try `git fetch` instead of `git pull`.

Comment: What if I already pushed the changes to the origin?
I found that "git reset upstream/master" just updates the head to the last commit of the (remote) forked repository which, in my case, already has the changes in there.

Comment: Made my day! Thank you for taking the time to help out!

Answer (score 18):

```
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```

or, shorter:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Or you can even take it one step further and setup an alias that will allow you to simply type `git scrub`:

```
git config --global alias.scrub 'reset --hard @{upstream}'
```

(This assumes that your branch is configured to track the corresponding remote branch, which it typically is, unless you are doing something special. See [`git-branch(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) for more details on tracking and [`git-rev-parse(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) for details on the branch specification syntax.)

And then you just `git push --force` to your fork, as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 11):

This would reset your master branch with the upstream master and if the branch has been updated since your forked it would pull those changes as well.

```
git checkout master 
git reset upstream/master
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push origin master --force
```

PS: Assuming Upstream is the original repo while origin is your copy.

Comment: It would appear as if you'd created your branch from a different commit.  The primary reason for rebasing is to maintain a linear project history.  That said, you should never rebase commits once they have been published to a public repository because this replaces old commits with new ones.  For details please see https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the method like this:

```
$REPO=<repo>
$ORIGIN=<user>/$REPO
$UPSTREAM=<upstream>/$REPO

$ git clone git@github.com:$ORIGIN.git
$ cd $REPO
$ git checkout master
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:$UPSTREAM.git
$ git reset --hard upstream/master
$ git pull --rebase upstream master
$ git push origin master --force
```

the output will show a warning:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': 
unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

So the correct way is put `git pull` before `git reset`:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:$ORIGIN.git
$ cd $REPO
$ git checkout master
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:$UPSTREAM.git
$ git pull --rebase upstream master
$ git reset --hard upstream/master
$ git push origin master --force
```

then the output will be like this:

```
From github.com:<upstream>/<repo>
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]          master     -> upstream/master
HEAD is now at 7a94b1790 Merge pull request #4237 from <upstream>/...
Current branch master is up to date.
Everything up-to-date.
```