# My pull request is being rejected because my master branch is out of sync. How do I get it in sync?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I'm sending in a pull request but the repo owner is rejecting it because my master is out of sync. I'm not sure how to bring it into sync.

I did a git pull to merge the original repo and my forked repo. Then I fixed any merge conflicts.

git pull upstream master

Not sure if this is fully accurate. Just need to know if there is anything else I need to be doing.

Comment: Yes, doing a `git pull` should normally fix this problem.  Have you tried pushing again?

Comment: Yea, I did. I'm going to try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your pull request is done from a dedicated branch, not from `master`.

That means all you need to do is:

```
 git fetch upstream
 git checkout my_PR_branch
 git rebase upstream/master
 git push --force
```

If you want, you can also [reset your local `master` branch to `upstream/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332860/6309) (assuming again that you have developpped your PR in its own branch)