# How can I overwrite all files in a GIT branch by another (upstream) branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a fork of a project in Github.

I accidentally committed and pushed local changes in my master branch to origin/master (Github).
The changes were by an automated script so about 180 files have been changed, so cannot manually revert the changes and make a new commit.

I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/using-git-how-to-go-back-to-a-previous-commit-8579ccc8180f) on rolling back to an old commit.

I've tried

```
  git checkout master
  git checkout <first commit-id> .
  git pull
  git commit -a -m "reverting back to older commit, so upstream can be cleanly merged"
  git push
  git fetch upstream
  git merge upstream/master
  git commit -a -m "updated with upstream/master"
  git push
```

However this doesn't update all files with the current code from upstream/master. All files are like the `<first commit-id>`.

If I had to guess GIT thinks the commit is newer than upstream/master so this is correct. But I don't know GIT that well.

Someone else suggested I should just remove the repo and re-fork the project.

But I'm guessing GIT should have an option to just replace/overwrite an entire (master) branch with an older version or just the current upstream/master?

Comment: Are you the sole contributor to the fork? If so, why don't you just undo the whole "accidental" thing with a `reset`? Unclear what the goal is here... Can you clarify?

Comment: @matt Yes it's a personal fork. From the answer from grg I found out I had to reset to upstream/master instead of my own master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

This will reset the current branch to the commit of upstream/master.

Comment: this is good if you want to get rid of all revisions after this one (and will require force-pushing if you have pushed the revisions you are getting rid of into a remote branch).

Comment: Thanks. Although your answer was not complete by searching this I found another answer which helped with the rest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332769/how-do-i-reset-the-git-master-branch-to-the-upstream-branch-in-a-forked-reposito , maybe you can edit/complete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a *new revision* on the branch (on top of what you have there) and that makes files content look like an *older revision*:

```
git checkout the-old-id
git reset --soft the-branch
# all differences will be in index, branch is not touched
git commit -m "going back to revision X"
# if you like the result, move the branch
git branch -f the-branch
git checkout the-branch
# push it to remote
```

The same can be done with `git read-tree` but I haven't tried it so can't build a recipe on it.