# How to "sync" a forked repository so it has the same state as the original repository?

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I did create a fork of a github repository using the API. Now after some while the fork and the original repository are out of sync.

How can I sync the fork to the same state as the original repository using the API or command line git commands?

I tried to remove the forked repository but I do not have the rights to remove it.

Re-forking the original repository also does not seem to work, I will have the message like

```
7 commits behind owner:master.
```

in the UI visible.

Any other idea?

---

I tried the solution #2 from [this page](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/3-ways-to-sync-a-forked-repository-on-github-automatically-cfd) but it did not work. I got many conflicts.

Just to be clear: I do not want to MERGE anything. I want to SYNC synchronize) the original repository with the forked repo, so the forked repo has the same state (history, commits, etc.) as the original repository. I do not want to merge anything, I want to SYNCHRONIZE it.

It is like in a programming language, when you have a python dictionary `mydict` which has some data and you want to just replace its content with a different python dict, you just do

```
mydict = other_dict
```

you also never get any "merge conflicts" by assigning the variable to some content.

I hope this is clearer now.

---

The problem is that I do not have direct access to the github GUI, otherwise I could just delete the fork and fork it again from the origin. But this does not work. I also do not have the rights to delete the fork using the API.

Comment: just do: `git pull owner master` when you are on `master`.

Comment: No does not seem to work, got a lot of conflicts!

Comment: Using the CLI, you should be able to do `gh repo sync owner/cli-fork`

Comment: Then `7 commits behind owner:master` message had to be incomplete. To have conflicts your branch have to have some commits ahead of `owner:master`. If you were just behind then pulling should not lead to a conflict, everything  should be resolved by fast forward.

Comment: Please copy paste everything `git status` prints.

Comment: you can also reset your branch to version matching remote: `git reset --hard owner/master` then your branch just have match `owner` and drop any changes you've made.

Comment: The `gh repo sync` idewa does not seem to work. I tried that and checked out the remote forked repository again, but it is missing several commits which are present on the original repository

Comment: @MarekR I do not expect to see any conflict. I just want to COPY all as it is. No merging involved AT ALL.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332769/how-do-i-reset-the-git-master-branch-to-the-upstream-branch-in-a-forked-reposito help

Comment: No sorry, I get conflicts again. This is not what I want.

Comment: It should work what was responded in comment. If it still does not work please copy paste exact contents of your command line so we have clear view what exactly you have done and what errors you see. Without it we can't provide anything more.

Comment: What commands should I try?

Comment: `$ git reset --hard BlueBrain/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'BlueBrain/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
`

Comment: I also updated my question to make clearer what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I sync [a GitHub] fork to the same state as the original repository using the API or command line git commands?

I don't know if `gh` has anything to do it, but from command-line Git you can get reasonably close with a combination of `git clone --mirror` and `git push --mirror`.  *Use these with great care* as `git push --mirror` can be quite destructive:

1. Run `git clone --mirror original-repository-URL` to create a mirror clone of the original repository.  This clone is only to be used for step 2, and then discarded.
2. Run `git push --mirror fork-repository-URL` to wipe out the current state of the fork and push all-new state.
3. Optional: Delete the mirror clone to prevent accidents with it.

I have not actually tried this with GitHub, and you might get warnings or even errors about `refs/pull/` references in step 2.  If this is a problem, add a "step 1.5":

- Run `git for-each-ref --format="git update-ref -d %(refname)" refs/pull | sh`

You may wish to run this without the `| sh` first, to make sure it generates the correct `git update-ref -d` commands.  This simply *deletes* all the `refs/pull/` names from the mirror clone, so that `git push --mirror` does not try to push them.