# git reset upstream/master Why do I get "fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Tags: git

I have forked a repo on github

I have cloned my fork locally

I did `git remote add upstream <the original repo>`

Now I want to reset my fork to match latest changes from `upstream`.

I thought this was the way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332860/202168

I followed those steps but when I get to `git reset --hard upstream/master` I get:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

What is wrong? How do I proceed?

Comment: Maybe the branch is called `main`? What about trying `git reset --hard upstream/main`?

Comment: Could you post the output of "git branch -r"? That should show us which remote branches are being tracked.

Comment: Have you run `git fetch upstream`? If not, your local git repository doesn't know about any remote branches - `git remote add` basically just writes some config entries, it doesn't actually contact the given URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git pull upstream master` should have combined:

- `git fetch upstream`
- `git merge upstream/master` to `master`

If that is not the case, check the `git config remote.upstream.fetch`: it should have a default refspec: `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*`.
That is what should produce remote tracking branches in the `upstream` namespace (see `git branch -avv`)

Comment: `git pull upstream master` has indeed done what I needed

Comment: This is also fix for this mistake: manually adding `[remote "upstream"]` to `git/config` by copy/pasting  `remote "origin"` block, but forgetting to also change the `fetch =` line to `upstream`. Once that's fixed you also need to re-run `git fetch upstream`.

Comment: @davetapley True. That is why I always try to avoid tinkering with the `.git/config` manually. Using `git config` commands should be safer.