# How to discard conflicts caused after rebasing in git and go back to the latest code pushed

Tags: java, git, eclipse, rebase, egit

Is there a way to disregard the changes made after my attempt to rebase and go back to the latest code I have pushed into main remote repository? Rebase left all the conflictinh classes with errors after it stacked two different versions into one class.

I made my latest changes in Eclipse and pushed them successfully into the main branch. When I was trying to submit a merge request I was asked to rebase due to a number of conflicting files. In the process of rebasing in Eclipse I had to compare versions of classes with a number of commits. I am new to working with Eclipse so I wasn’t sure how to “pick” my local changes instead of the ones from the earlier commits. Because of this issue git put together both versions into one class which was too we convoluted for me to sort through. I am now left with 5 classes that are have a bunch of errors and it would be easier if I could just pull the code that I had successfully pushed to start fresh.

What is the easiest way to do this without running into the same issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset the git master branch to the upstream branch in a forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332769/how-do-i-reset-the-git-master-branch-to-the-upstream-branch-in-a-forked-reposito). The answers there show ways to reset to the upstream master, but they do so using the console, not the eclipse integration.

Comment: See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/Tasks.html#Resetting_your_current_HEAD

Comment: @Hulk This question is not about the command line Git.