Is it possible to demote "master" to a sub-branch (with its entire structure) and create a new master?
There is a repository, "X", that I forked and began doing work on to migrate it to the Jetson Nano.  This fork's "master" has several branches and is a number of commits ahead and behind the original master it was forked from. In order to participate in another project I've been invited to contribute to, I need a fresh, pristine, copy of the original repository. The obvious answer is to create a new fork, but that's not possible here in GitHub without creating an organization, which is more trouble for me than it's worth.
Therefore the solution becomes to demote the existing "master" to the status of a branch, (maintaining the structure of all its subsidiary branches), and re-clone the existing repository to a new "master" that things can branch from. (And create a new branch for the new project.)
In other words, given this structure:
main <== modified so it's != to the original "master" it was forked from
branch-a
branch-b
branch-c

I want it to become:
master <== freshly copied/forked/cloned from the original pristine master
old-master
branch-a
branch-b
branch-c
new-branch <== for project 'B' - I know how to make new branches, if I can get the "master" done correctly

This essentially becomes two main questions:

How do I demote the existing "master" to the status of a branch, rename it, and create a new "master" that it is a branch of? It would be sufficient to copy the entire master/branch structure to another branch.

How do I populate the new "master" branch with the original data so that the other branches have a new root-master they're based on?


The following questions:

How can I make a second fork of a GitHub project?
Rename master-branch and create a new, empty master
Insert a commit before the root commit in Git?

appear to almost answer my question, but (as far as I can tell) they really don't.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch? Not sure what you mean by a "sub branch" or the "structure" of a branch, they're all just pointers to commits.

your first question - you just rename the branch.

If I "rename the branch", how do I create the new "master" branch that it is a branch of?
A "sub-branch" would be a branch of a branch. (see the structural diagram I provided.

You could try pulling - that may just bring in the missing master branch (you want the original master branch, right?)

Also as noted by jonrsharpe, a branch of a branch is not a sub-branch, its just a branch. It's branches all the way down (well, not really, its commits all the way down).

Possibly you just want https://stackoverflow.com/q/42332769/3001761; unless you've been rebasing or otherwise updating the other branches they will still be the same as upstream anyway. master already has "the status of a branch", it's a branch. Any semantics are on the user (or GitHub, in the specific case of the "default branch").

@topsail [so] has its own [meta] site given their question is related to a question on this site suggesting to ask on this site's Meta would have been better.

This question is a two step duplicate: 1) git: how to rename a branch (both local and remote)? and then 2) How to get a new branch in my fork from the original repository?

There are no sub branches - just a main/master branch and other branches; each of the branches can be local, remote, or both; one of the branches will be set as the upstream branch that you fetch from by default. I've had to something similar and this is how I would achieve it. (I will use "master", but newer version git repos use "main")
repopath0=~/you/repos/X.git
repopath1=~/you/repos/NEW.git

projpath0=~/you/proj/X
projpath1=~/you/proj/NEW

newbranch="identifiable-as-old-proj-branch"
oldreponame="identifiable-as-old-proj-repo"

cd $projpath1
git checkout -b "${newbranch}-master"

git remote add $oldreponame $projpath0
git fetch project-oldmaster --tags
git status # you should now see all the branches from your old repo
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories $oldreponame/master

# repeat steps beginning with cd $projpath1 for each of your "minor" branches replacing "master" with the name of the branch.

This is how I did it with self hosted git repos.
There was an issue with older servers that had older versions of git, which left me with having to omit the "--tags" (you lose tagging) "--allow-unrelated-histories", but it still worked as far as merging. I would upgrade git if these are needed.
That being said GitHub uses git, but it is a remote hosting platform so you'll have to use what they provide you access to. You'll need to setup terminal access. This may help: GitHub help
